# AnyChart Resource Chart How to add event listener for activities

Tags: anychart

In researching the **AnyChart** documentation for **Resource Charts**, it seems as though you should be able to add an event listener for `Activities`, but I have been unable to get it working.

**AnyChart Resource Chart demo**
http://playground.anychart.com/api/7.12.0/core/resource/anychart.core.resource.Activities.labels_get-plain

**AnyChart documentation ( specific to Resource Chart Activities )**
https://api.anychart.com/7.12.0/anychart.core.resource.Activities#listen

Adding a listener event to the chart itself works as expected, but does not provide any data specific to the individual activity the user clicked.

I need to add the listener event to the `Activities` object so that when a user selects/clicks a specific activity within the chart, the listener event fires and returns data specific to that activity.

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    var data = getData();

    chart = anychart.resource();
    chart.data(data);

    var currentActivities = chart.activities();

    // this listener event never fires for the activities object
    currentActivities.listen('click', function(e) {
        // expecting to get an event object specific to the activity clicked by user here
    });

    chart.container("container");
    chart.draw();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 7.13.0 that will be released next Monday/Tuesday will allow this. Here is a preview build:

```
chart.listen("pointClick", function(e){
            console.log(e.data);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2f2wt553/2/

Previous versions do not have that.